# Swift PUT call not sending headers to API

Tags: swift, api, rest

So I'm trying to call a PUT method on an Amazon API I am currently using in Swift. The code I have uses URLSessions, and is as follows:

```
func putMethod() {
    guard let url = URL(string: API url) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    
    // Create model
    struct UploadData: Codable {
        let Name: String
        let Birthday: String
        let Email: String
    }
    
    // Add data to the model
    let uploadDataModel = UploadData(Name: "Mat", Birthday: "03-18-1922", Email: "email@gmail.com")
    
    // Convert model to JSON data
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    guard let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(uploadDataModel) else {
        print("Error: Trying to convert model to JSON data")
        return
    }
    
    // Create the request
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.addValue("314", forHTTPHeaderField: "UserId")
    request.addValue("08-24-2022", forHTTPHeaderField: "CreateDate")
    request.addValue("Rand0mTe6t1ng314", forHTTPHeaderField: "IntUserID")
    request.addValue(API key, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
    
    request.httpMethod = "PUT"
    
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error: error calling PUT")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Error: Did not receive data")
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200 ..< 299) ~= response.statusCode else {
            print("Error: HTTP request failed")
            return
        }
        do {
            guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else {
                print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
                return
            }
            guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
                return
            }
            guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                print("Error: Could print JSON in String")
                return
            }
            
            print(prettyPrintedJson)
        } catch {
            print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
            return
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

However, when I run this, I haven't actually put anything into my API, it lists the `UserID` header as a NIL value. Is there a glaring error I am making when handling PUT requests in Swift using multiple headers, while using an authentication key? Thanks!

Comment: from the code you show, you are using `UserId` in the header field, not `UserID`, note the difference.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine i actually didnt notice that little thing. When i change that in my code, still nothing sends sadly. is there anything else i might have missed in my code? thanks!

Comment: can you tell/show us what the server expect to receive. Note, this header looks suspicious: `IntUserID` but you are sending a String.

Comment: Yes, the serve is expecting 4 headers: `UserID`, `CreateDate`, `IntUserID`, and `x-api-key`. Just as an extra I guess reassurance, this is the Python code that Postman generated, which actually does work:
```import requests
url = API Url

payload={}
headers = {
  'UserID': '124',
  'CreateDate': '08-24-2002',
  'IntUserID': 'Rand0mTe6t1ng124',
  'x-api-key': API Key
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```
Edit: Sorry about the formatting, I'm not sure how to better format it in a comment

Comment: is your url a `http` or `https` as required?

Comment: my url uses `https`, and works in the python code, as well as in the cURL command

Comment: running out of ideas. As I recall, there were a number of similar cases before, and it was due to using a different (or incorrect) api key, so check the api key you are using.

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure, because when i try and modify parts of the api key, i get the appropriate message that it is forbidden. is there any reason why this might work with postman and python and curl, but not specifically with `URLSession` within Swift?